# I want to install old version package in R

Tags: r

I want to install blavaan_0.2-4 version package.
My installing codes are

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/blavaan/blavaan_0.2-4.tar.gz",
             repos = NULL, type="source",dependancies=TRUE)
```

or

```
install.packages("https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/blavaan/blavaan_0.2-4.tar.gz",repos = NULL, type="source")
```

But i got this kind of error

ERROR: dependency 'runjags' is not available for package 'blavaan'

* removing 'C:/Users/mvstat/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/blavaan'
Warning in install.packages :

installation of package ‘C:/Users/mvstat/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpgZXrEO/downloaded_packages/blavaan_0.2-4.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

how can I solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know what versions of all the dependencies you want to install? You can try `install.packages("runjags")` to get the current version of the required dependency.

Comment: thank you!! but when i run the function, i get this error :
`  `
blavaan NOTE: Arguments ov.cp and lv.cp are deprecated. Use cp instead. 
Unable to call JAGS using 'findjags()' - try specifying the path to the JAGS binary as the jags
argument, or installing the rjags package.  Use the testjags() function for more detailed
diagnostics.
`  `

Comment: You need JAGS installed on your computer. That must be done outside R. See the INSTALL guide: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/runjags/INSTALL

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
require(devtools)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "0.9.1", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```